# Mesh from imported sketchup model is not good enough for animations, gives weird reflections

Tags: modeling

I've imported a model from sketchup, where I filled two curved lines to get a mesh. The problem is that when I want to use it for an animation, the reflections show up weird on the final render.
Is there any way to fix the mesh/ make the material appear smooth?

[image: The reflections are weird, I just want the material to appear smooth]

[image: The mesh illustrated.]

Comment: It will probably take you far less time to model something like that cleanly from scratch, than it will take you to clean that up to an acceptable state

Comment: Hello ! Your mesh may suffer from any and all of these : inverted normals, double vertices, Z fighting and inside faces. Also the quad distribution should be as even as possible to avoid shading artifacts, especially on curved surfaces